# set value date to Jspinner as time format

Tags: java, swing, date, netbeans

I have string saved on database "Sun Jun 28 13:44:35 WIB 2020", and I set my spinner only show time format HH:mm:ss

```
Date date = new Date();
SpinnerDateModel sm = 
        new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
jSpinner1 = new javax.swing.JSpinner(sm);
JSpinner.DateEditor de = new JSpinner.DateEditor(jSpinner1, "HH:mm:ss");
jSpinner1.setEditor(de);
```

I want to set my string "Sun Jun 28 13:44:35 WIB 2020" into the spinner as time,
I've tried with this

```
String cok = "Sun Jun 28 13:44:35 WIB 2020";
jSpinner1.setValue(cok);
```

and error illegal value cause I've to casting the string, I don't know what's date format it is.

How to convert the string into that format and then setValue into spinner ?

Comment: Date pattern is `HH:mm:ss` but you are giving value `Sun Jun 28 13:44:35 WIB 2020`.

Comment: yes,but I don't know what syntax to convert to HH:mm:ss from string , I'm new on java ...

Comment: Pattern is `HH:mm:ss`, value should be like `13:44:35`. [Check for formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Why would you be displaying a moment in a spinner widget? A spinner is for a set of incremental values.

Comment: @BasilBourque,because i need timepicker on java and i won't using any library / plugin so i set my jspinner into time format

Comment: `SpinnerDateModel` and friends use the old classes `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. You may see if you can find a more modern GUI component instead.